# How to Disable html button in django?

Tags: javascript, python, django

i am beginner in python and django.

I want to disable HTML "Register" button . once '**plugin registered successfully**' this message will appear.

currently i am returning the message in json response using

```
return JsonResp(request,message=_('vCenter plugin registered successfully.'),)
```

here is the code ..

```
def vcp_home(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = VcenterConfigurationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        if form.vcp_register():
           form.save()
           extFact=ExtensionRegister.ExtensionFactory()
           obj = models.VcenterConfiguration.objects.latest('id')
           obj.vc_version=extFact.get_pluginVersion();
           obj.save()
           form.check_update()
           return JsonResp(request,message=_('plugin registered successfully.'),)
        else:
          return JsonResp(request, error=True, message=_(form.vcp_status))
           #return JsonResp(request,message=_(form.vcp_status),)
else:
    try:
      obj = models.VcenterConfiguration.objects.latest('id')
      form = VcenterConfigurationForm(instance=obj)
      form.check_update()
    except :
       form = VcenterConfigurationForm()
       form.check_update()
return render(request, "vcp/index.html", {
'form': form
})
```

Comment: Your indentation is messed up..

Comment: .. and also, this is a javascript/ajax issue. Disabling dom-elements after the page has been rendered cannot happen from the server.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this is to submit your form using ajax and then parse the response and then disable button based on that response.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#YOUR_FORM').submit(function() {
                $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
                    data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
                    type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
                    url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
                    success: function(response) { // on success..
                        //check the response and disable submit button
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```